# I am not able Training models in sklearn (scikit-learn) using python

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

i have data file it contain data to predict the admission in MS.
it contain 9 column 8 column contain student data and 9th column contain chance of selection of student.
i am new and i don't understand error come in training model

```
import pandas 
import numpy as np 
import sklearn as sl 
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
classifier = MLPClassifier()


data = pandas.read_csv('Addmition.csv')
data_array = np.array(data)

X = data_array[:,1:8]
y = data_array[:,8]

classifier.fit(X,y)
print(classifier)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 14, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X,y)
  File "C:\Users\vishal jangid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 977, in fit
    hasattr(self, "classes_")))
  File "C:\Users\vishal jangid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 324, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
  File "C:\Users\vishal jangid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 920, in _validate_input
    self._label_binarizer.fit(y)
  File "C:\Users\vishal jangid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 413, in fit
    self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
  File "C:\Users\vishal jangid\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 96, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
ValueError: Unknown label type: (array
```

Comment: Next time, please post your error *after* the code, and not before (edited)...

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**:

```
import numpy as np 
import sklearn as sl 
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
classifier = MLPRegressor()


data = pandas.read_csv('Addmition.csv')
data_array = np.array(data)

X = data_array[:,1:8]
y = data_array[:,8]

classifier.fit(X,y)
print(classifier)
```

**Explanation**:

In machine learning we may have two types of problems:

1) Classification:
Ex: Predict if a person is male or female. (discrete)

2) Regression:
Ex: Predict the age of the person. (continuous)

With this in hand we are going to see your problem, your label (chance of selection) is continous, thus we have a regression problem.

See that you are using the MLPClassifier, resulting in the 'Unknown label error'.
Try using the [MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering